# Plot only date ticks on y axis on pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have CSV data in the following form:

```
2017-02-28 22:10:48 1488330648 18
2017-02-28 22:10:38 1488330638 18
2017-02-28 22:10:28 1488330628 18
2017-02-28 22:10:18 1488330618 18
2017-02-28 22:10:08 1488330608 18
```

(the last '18' is the data for the y axis)

The full dataset covers several weeks (this is just a sample). When I plot it the y axis in unreadable as you can see below. How could I arrange it so it shows ticks for each day only?

[image: ugly axis plot]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `lines.tight_layout()` ?

Reference: http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html

Comment: There was an error in my parsing of the timestamp, so it was interpreting them as strings, not datetimes.